# Conditionally render spinner while waiting for list to render

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which is being used to render several different cards. These cards take some time to be rendered and I would like to display the `CircularProgress` spinner which has been imported via Material-UI.

I'm not sure how to achieve this, I have seen some posts on Stack using some sort of loading state, but not sure how that would fit into this particular component.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Home.css';
import Layout from '../../components/Layout/Layout';
import Card from '../../components/Card/Card';
import img from './level-1.jpg';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

const Home = ({ levels = {}, setCurrentLevel }) => {

    const gameLevels = levels.map((level) => {
        return (
            <Link to="/game" onClick={() => setCurrentLevel(level.id)}>
                <Card key={level.id} level={level} />
            </Link>
        );
    });

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className="main-container">
                <div className="grid-container">
                    {gameLevels}
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: What you're looking for is lazyloading components - here is a tutorial that I really liked when I first needed it - https://blog.logrocket.com/lazy-loading-components-in-react-16-6-6cea535c0b52/

Comment: Relevant [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5ym1vlpmjl?file=/src/index.js) - see the suspense component

Comment: Thanks @Ayushya - I will have a look at these! :)

Comment: @Tjm92 It depends on the source for `levels` If it is coming as a result of some `XHR` i.e. from an API request. 

You can keep a loading state as you mentioned in your description. It would be sufficient if you can update the description with that parent component where you are making that request.

Comment: Thanks @Jawadulhassan - I have made some amendments to where the API call for levels is being made and included a loading boolean. This is now pushed down into the component and is working - thank you!